# Are refresh token grants now allowed on third party apps?

Tags: social-tables

I see that you previously did not allow refresh token grants of access tokens from third party apps. The most recent I was able to find on this was as of 2016. Has this since changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently support refresh_token grants, but we have not updated our public documentation with this OAuth flow.

To use refresh tokens, capture the refresh_token parameter in the response from the POST /4.0/oauth/token endpoint during the normal authorization_code grant flow, and make a subsequent request to POST /4.0/oauth/token with the refresh_token grant type when necessary. To enable this flow, you may need to edit and re-save your app's configuration in the developer portal.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried to use this, making a request with ruby's oauth2 gem:

`client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, { :site => DOMAIN, :token_url => PATH_TOKEN })
token = client.get_token({:grant_type => 'refresh_token', :refresh_token => refresh_token, :client_id => CLIENT_ID, :client_secret => CLIENT_SECRET})`

And I only get a 504 error, with no actual response. Is anything missing from the request?

Comment: Hard to say from the boilerplate you posted; can you provide your client ID so I can try to find your request in our logs?

Comment: cjfslsyn900s10i4d16u3tumz

Comment: I have looked into our logs, but was unable to find an OAuth refresh token request between Monday and Today. Please try the flow manually using the developer console (https://developer.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Authentication/post_4_0_oauth_token), as doing so should help to isolate any potential API issues from Ruby gem issues.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Since the authorization code grants work fine, I'm going to stick with those. The previous attempts via the dev console have worked fine, but the Ruby gem just isn't working. Thanks for your quick followup.